# Name of the Song in Naruto 373

Tags: naruto, theme-song

I couldn't find the name of the song in this particular video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klUlGDTjvbU about 16:30. It's from episode 373 while the squad fights the spawns of 10 tailed beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This song originally appeared in the episode where Chiyo & Sakura fight Sasori.

The name of the song is Reverse Situation.Sonetimes also read as Turn the Tables. ( Kesei Gyakuten.)

It is track number 26 in Naruto Shippuden original soundtrack (by Yasuharu Takanashi).[Naruto Shippuden Original Soundtrack](https://itunes.apple.com/de/album/naruto-shippuden-original-soundtrack/1006254330?l=en)

It also has a remix version called Spin and Burst from the soundtrack of the movie "Boruto- Naruto the Movie".This is an amazing song as well.[Boruto : Naruto the Movie Original Soundtrack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YAZ90BG)